# Instagram API not returning json

Tags: php, json, facebook, api, instagram

The login is working fine. But I can't get the data via the `access_token`. How to get the data? My app is in Sandbox Mode by the way. Does it makes a difference? I am logging in using the same account as the admin of the app.

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);
    session_start();

    // instagram details
    define('clientID', MY-ID);
    define('clientSecret', MY-SECRET);
    define('redirectURI', 'http://localhost/pixela/insta_test.php');

    // check login
    $link = '<a href="http://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id='.clientID.'&redirect_uri='.redirectURI.'&response_type=code">Login to Instagram</a>';

    if (isset($_GET["code"])) {
        $code = $_GET["code"];
        $url = 'http://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token';
        $access_token_settings = array (
            'client_id' => clientID,
            'client_secret' => clientSecret,
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri' => redirectURI,
            'code' => $code
        );

        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $access_token_settings);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        $results = json_decode($result, true);
        echo 'u-'.$results['user']['username'];

        $link = '<a href="">Get photos</a>';
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing Instagram API</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php echo $link; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

[When not logged in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwxzy.png)

[When logged in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btvZL.png)